# How to access actor created in a websocket?

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka, playframework-2.3

I have a websocket created with the play 2.3 web socket actor feature. How can I access the actor created to send messages in other function?

```
def websocket: WebSocket[JsValue, JsValue] = 
  WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] {
    req => out => Props(new MyActor(out))
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Give to your actor a reference to a manager:

```
def websocket: WebSocket[JsValue, JsValue] = 
  WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] {
    req => out => Props(new MyActor(managerRef, out))
  }
```

And make your actor register to your manager in `preStart`.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit please. What do you mean by "register", and what happens when that WebSocket is closed? How does the manager know of the death of the actor it is managing?. Sorry if I have missed something obvious here, I am new to Akka

Comment: "register" => in `preStart`, send a message to your manager, the manager may do whatever (save the sender in a set, for example)
When the WebSocket is closed, the `MyActor` instance is killed (by Play)
The manager may `watch` (method in `ActorContext`) your `MyActor` instance when it registered.